# Volumes with docker microsoft/iis

Tags: c#, azure, iis, docker, docker-for-windows

I was trying to attach a volume to the docker container but none of the ways I tried worked. I am working with an Azure Windows 2016 vm
Here the docker info:

```
Containers: 2
Running: 1
Paused: 0
Stopped: 1
Images: 108
Server Version: 1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: nat null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.321.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161004-2338)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7 GiB
Name: wfgendocker
ID: QBKJ:RZAU:ADAI:WS4U:JV2K:IB5I:52K6:MWTD:NS3X:KRP6:SH6T:QKDT
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

So in my docker file I am copying over my IIS website into inetpub/root
and my goal is to mount /inetpub on the container to the local machine so changes to the scripts and web.config can be done at run time.

At first I tried VOLUME /inetpub in the dockerfile which build successfully, but then when I ran the container, it give me the following error.

> encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The directory is not empty

But there is no mention anywhere in the docker documentation about the volume needing to be empty.

So then I tried attaching the volume at run, such as, docker run -p 80:80 -v C:/build/inetpub:C:/inetpub web/iis .
this gave me the same error as above. but when i try
docker run -p 80:80 -v C:/build/inetpub:C:/randomtest web/iis .
it works, but I can't modify the files else the container stops.

The last thing I tried was working with docker-compose, 
in my service I have 
volumes:
- ./inetpub:/inetpub
which give the following error

> Cannot create container for service wfgen: invalid volume spec "/inetpub": invalid volume specification

I tried many variations of - ./inetpub:/inetpub but they always gave me the same error.

Thanks for any help, I ve been stuck on this for days without any results.

Here is my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206
SHELL ["powershell"]

#adding windows features to vm
RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45

#temp tempfile
RUN mkdir C:\temp
#adding wfgen_admin user to vm
RUN mkdir C:\createUser
COPY createUser/ /createUser
RUN createUser/wfgen_adminCreate.ps1

#installing the services and starting them
RUN mkdir C:\aprogramfiles
COPY wfgenServices/ /aprogramfiles
RUN aprogramfiles/.\winsvc-install.cmd
#copying wfgen webcontent to vm
COPY inetpub/wwwroot/ /inetpub/wwwroot
RUN createUser/wfgen_admin_grant_access.ps1
#removing default website that runs on port 80
RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'

#creating a new iis website with the copied wfgen website i am not sure if i have the right commands here
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
        Import-module IISAdministration; \
    New-IISSite -Name "wfgenroot" -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot -   BindingInformation "*:80:";
    #converting weforms and ws to applications
RUN ConvertTo-WebApplication "IIS:/Sites/wfgenroot/wfgen";
RUN ConvertTo-WebApplication "IIS:/Sites/wfgenroot/wfgen/WfApps/WebForms";
RUN ConvertTo-WebApplication "IIS:/Sites/wfgenroot/wfgen/ws"
#Setting the authentication type of the website
RUN Set-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication 'IIS:/Sites/wfgenroot' -value @{mode='Windows'}
RUN Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name enabled -value true -PSPath 'IIS:/Sites/wfgenroot/wfgen'
RUN New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation createUser -DnsName 127.0.0.1
RUN New-WebBinding -Name "wfgenroot" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https
RUN $Thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "127.0.0.1"}).Thumbprint;
RUN get-item Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My\$Thumbprint | new-item 0.0.0.0!443

#RUN createUser/appcmdrun.ps1
#exposing port 80
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
WORKDIR /inetpub
```

Comment: The container is based of microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206

Comment: Could you please paste your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

So I've just tried this:

> docker run --rm -v c:/folder:c:/somefolder microsoft/iis

and it works perfectly, I can create files, I can delete them, etc.
docker info:
C:\Users\core>docker info

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 6
Server Version: 1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: nat null overlay transparent
Swarm: inactive
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.321.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161004-2338)
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.865 GiB
Name: pytop
ID: FENS:OO6R:J273:I5BB:2OGZ:HAMM:6YFX:53BP:XBA5:G3LE:QNKE:FLJ3
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

I'm using docker beta.

Comment: yes, when i do docker run --rm -v c:/folder:c:/temp wfgen/iis it works fine, but temp is empty, I need it to be the inetpub directory which contains the site content and configs. Also I have noticed many difference between windows 10 docker and windows server 2016 docker especially since its an azure vm.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Just like I said, when I do this all the files and folders get mapped correctly, i can edit them, delete them etc

Answer (score 0):

This is because at the moment windows containers support only empty directories. I needed to map only logs volume and this command in Dockerfile helped me:

```
RUN ["powershell", "Remove-Item", "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Portals\\Logs\\*", "-Recurse"]
```

Then I simply issued `docker run --rm -d -p 8000:80 -v c:/Logs:c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Portals/Logs --name site-v my-image-name`
Got info from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/497/#issuecomment-262392453).